# Is there any method using R to access Google Analytics v3?

Tags: r, google-analytics

I am searching a new R method to access Google Analytics v3 since the previous script don't work anymore.

I can't find any helpful information about this so if anyone is using R to access GA v3, please help me out.

Comment: What and where is 'the previous script'?

Comment: Here for V2.3 : http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/

Comment: What exactly does not work?  Have you verified that any required upgrades to supporting libraries have been installed?

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Keplar](http://www.keplarllp.com/blog/2012/01/using-google-analytics-export-to-csv-a-step-by-step-guide) a feasible solution to a similar problem (exploit data logged in  GA using R ) It is OK for me at least temporary. 
Actually Keplar is query a tool written in Java and it was embedded easily in my processes. Till this solution, I've checked many other ideas ( Python API from GA, other GA API,  etc.) This small tool helped me a lot and wish you the same. :)